# Issues connecting JS/jQuery files with WordPress causes header to disappear

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, header

I'm having issues adding jQuery/JavaScript files to my custom Bootstrap WordPress theme.

Here is the tutorial I'm using to build my theme (Please DO NOT criticize me for using something that's 3 years old. [There's just a few modifications needed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UKah.png)

Here are the files I would like to add to the functions.php file:

```
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <script src="js/vendor/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

Here is what I have tried, the first one following the tutorial from it being a jquery file. The other two are having issues.

When I apply these and the

```
wp_footer();
```

The header disappears as shown below.

Also having problems with the jQuery file that is from the jQuery library online.

```
wp_register_script( 'custom-script', get_template_directory_uri() . 'js/vendor/jquery-1.11.2.min.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
wp_register_script( 'custom-script', get_template_directory_uri() . 'js/vendor/bootstrap.min.js', array() );
wp_register_script( 'custom-script', get_template_directory_uri() . 'js/main.js', array() );</pre></code>
```

[image: Header disappearing when wp_footer(); is applied in footer.php]

[Sites I've looked at](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script)

Answer (score 0):

when you are using `wp_enqueue_script`, the handle name ( first attribute ) must be uniqe for each one. so try following code.

```
function my_bootstrap_scripts() {
   wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
   wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/vendor/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), '', true);
   wp_enqueue_script('main-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/main.js', array('jquery'), '', true);
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_bootstrap_scripts');
```

Comment: It works except when I try and add a online script such as:
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-lib-online', '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js', array('jquery'), '', true);

Found it here:
http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/82940/how-can-i-enqueue-protocol-relative-external-ajax-googleapis-com-scripts

Comment: please try adding full file url with http  like this,

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js